# Mongo Export dump of collections inserted after specific day and time

Tags: mongodb, epoch, mongoexport

I am trying to dump all the entries made in a MongoDB since midnight each day. I created a unix script that uses 'mongoexport' utlity. It is returning zero records. Here are the commands.

```
# Generate a variable that stores today's date and 00:00 hours in epoch format
toDay=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
todayMidnightEpoch=$(date -d "${toDay} 00:00:00" "+%s")

# Now plug this epoch variable into mongoexport command
mongoexport \
--host <hostname> \
--username <user ID> \
--password <password> \
--db <db name> \
--limit 100000 \
--collection <collection name> \
--out filename-$(date +%Y%m%d).json \
--query '{created_at:{"$gte": "new Date(${todayMidnightEpoch})"}}'
```

1. I am running this script on CentOS+MongoDB server.
2. I tested the mongoexport command with no query option and I get the output of all documents almost immediately.

I get zero records after running for more than 10-20 minutes. 
When I run the same 'query' with the variable replaced by actual epoch value on Mongo Shell I get the right output instantaneously.

```
db.<collection name>.find('{"created_at":{"$gte":new Date(140013360000000)}}')
```

Even when I hard coded the epoch value in the mongoexport command, I got one record.

```
mongoexport --host <hostname> --username <username> --password <password> --db <db name> --limit 10 --collection <coll name> --out test-$(date +%Y%m%d).json --query '{created_at:{$gte:new Date(1431561600000)}}'
```

Questions:

- Why does it return the records (or documents) when a query is run with hard coded epoch value in mongo shell but not when it is passed through a unix variable in mongoexport utility?
- Is there a way to specify today's date and time as 00:00:00 in the query option without having to convert it into epoch format?

Answer (score 3):

You need to modify your epoch time like this:

```
newtodayMidnightEpoch=$(($todayMidnightEpoch*1000))
```

You need to change your query line to this:

```
--query "{created_at:{\"\$gte\": new Date(${newtodayMidnightEpoch})}}"
```

You need to use double quotes not single quotes around the entire string as single quotes prevent variable substitution, and then you need to remove the double quotes around the new Date( string as it's incorrect syntax. You also need to pass the epoch in milliseconds not seconds. When I make that change plus escaping the double quotes around $gte with a backslash it works fine for me.

So the complete new script would be:

```
# Generate a variable that stores today's date and 00:00 hours in epoch format
toDay=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
todayMidnightEpoch=$(date -d "${toDay} 00:00:00" "+%s")
newtodayMidnightEpoch=$(($todayMidnightEpoch*1000))


# Now plug this epoch variable into mongoexport command
mongoexport \
--host <hostname> \
--username <user ID> \
--password <password> \
--db <db name> \
--limit 100000 \
--collection <collection name> \
--out filename-$(date +%Y%m%d).json \
--query "{created_at:{\"\$gte\": new Date(${newtodayMidnightEpoch})}}"
```

Comment: Sorry, it didn't help. It ran the same amount of time and returned only one record.

Comment: Forgot one thing - you need to pass epoch in milliseconds, not seconds - will update answer

Comment: Yes, I was multiplying the value with 1000 to get it in milliseconds.

Comment: Giving the `\$gte` resolved the problem. Creating an index on `created_at` field speeded the query. Thanks.